# Get variable on Wordpress to PHP

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, get

I'm trying to get a value of a form in Wordpress to PHP. The form is like this and it is displaying fine in the preview:

```
<form action=".../name.php" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="form_ques_4" value=0 />
<input type="checkbox" name="form_ques_4" value=1 />
<input type="checkbox" name="form_ques_4" value=2 />
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

If the user selected option 2, the value is 1 and this will later be used as the input in a MySQL database. As I have read in other posts, I should get value with the php line.

```
$a = $_GET["form_ques_4"];
```

I have tested some other simple outputs for the .php and there is no problem with the "form action" of the wordpress. I also tried using single and double quotes for the "GET" with no result.

Comment: As I remember you can't use the same name for all checkbox elements, maybe you want to use type="radio"

Comment: for checkbox: name="form_ques_4[]"

Comment: @Rafael Chow Only the problem with your input `attribute name`, that should not be same name, if you want same name to use you should use name like this `form_ques_4[]`, so that will `POST` as array of selected values `form_ques_4[1]` , `form_ques_4[2]` , `form_ques_4[3]` , `form_ques_4[4]`.. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the names of your checkboxes, if you want a user multiple choice:

```
<form action=".../name.php" method="get">
     <input type="checkbox" name="form_ques_1" value="0" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="form_ques_2" value="1" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="form_ques_3" value="2" />
     <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

otherwise, if you want the user makes only one choice use `type="radio"`

```
<form action=".../name.php" method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="form_ques_4" value="0" />
    <input type="radio" name="form_ques_4" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="form_ques_4" value="2" />
     <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**EDIT** 
yes, as AZinkey says, you can also use

```
<form action=".../name.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="form_ques[]" value="0" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="form_ques[]" value="1" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="form_ques[]" value="2" />
     <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

then get the results in php

```
$checked = $_GET['form_ques'];
for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
    echo $checked[$i] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Quote your value attribute like **`value="0"`** and update name to "**form_ques_4[]**"

```
<input type="checkbox" name="form_ques_4[]" value="0" />
```